# Difference between gawk vs. awk

Tags: awk, gawk

Trying to understand the differences between the two functions gawk vs. awk? When would one use gawk vs awk? Or are they the same in terms of usage?

Also, could one provide an example?

Comment: Googling found an answer [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/awk-nawk-gawk/)

Comment: @hesse can you provide an example?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is a programming language. There are [several implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) of AWK (mostly in the form of interpreters). AWK has been [codified in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html).
The main implementations in use today are:

- `nawk` (“new awk”, an evolution of `oawk`, the original UNIX implementation), used on *BSD and widely available on Linux;
- [`mawk`](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/), a fast implementation that mostly sticks to standard features;
- [`gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), the GNU implementation, with many extensions;
- the
  [Busybox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) (small, intended for embedded systems, not many features).

If you only care about standard features, call `awk`, which may be Gawk or nawk or mawk or some other implementation. If you want the features in GNU awk, use `gawk` or Perl or Python.

Comment: Actually, the BusyBox `awk` is pretty close in behavior to `gawk` v3; I think it's more full-featured than `nawk`.

Comment: Good summary. **A note for Debian users**:  The `buster` release included a [1996 release of `mawk`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/mawk). The recent `bullseye` release [brought us up to a 2020 version - 1.3.4](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/mawk). Oddly perhaps - *at least on my RPi OS `buster` system* - the 1996 `mawk` was never updated/upgraded during 3 years of use.

Comment: Update `awk` link in latest [IEEE 1003.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)